# Laravel session data over websocket

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, websocket, phpwebsocket

Recently I have being playing with a project I found on github called Laravel Websocket Poker (https://github.com/troymccormick/laravel-pkr/). I have it all running and working well. When you open the game page, you a presented with a dialog for your chosen username. I want to modify this, so that the session data of the current user is able to be used within the websockets.

So my question is, how can I associate the users laravel session info with their websocket connection?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered getting in touch with the repository owner: he has disclosed his email in the readme.md!

Comment: Yeah, no reply as of yet though :(

Comment: BTW, it's a Laravel 3 project.